# Como criar uma View para telas com largura menor que X

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, razor

Tenho um site MVC4, que não é responsivo, e mudar toda a sua implementação só para o tornar responsivo não me parece nada produtivo, pois é um site onde trabalharam muitas pessoas e há muita "tralhar" por trás que vai complicar-me a vida.

A minha ideia era criar `Views` do zero, mas essas só seriam apresentados em dispositivos *mobile*. Desta maneira construía o site em bootstrap, e quando tivesse as páginas suficientes usava essas *views* para serem apresentadas sempre em qualquer ecrã (como planeio fazer com bootstrap vai funcionar tudo direito).

Vi uns artigos em que se adicionava o `.Mobile` no `_Layout.cshtml`, ficando `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` porém não me parece que seja exatamente o que procuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de desenvolver segmentando pelo tamanho da tela é usando o CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        /* Estilos caso a tela tenha 480px de largura ou mais */
    }
}
```

Basicamente, você pode usar 4 tipos de mídia:

- All (todos os tipos);
- Print (layout de impressão);
- Screen (tela);
- Speech (um software ou dispositivo de fala).

Você pode também fazer o MVC identificar o *User Agent* (no caso, a versão do navegador) e devolver um layout específico para ele, conforme você especificou na sua pergunta. [Aqui tem uma descrição bem completa de como usar](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/multiple-views-and-displaymode-providers-in-asp-net-mvc-4/), mas, basicamente é só usar o seguinte no seu `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var displayModes = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes;

    ...
}
```

Apenas isso já habilita o uso de um `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` ou de *Views* com `.Mobile.cshtml`, sendo que o MVC faz a troca do layout automaticamente para você.